# What are exercises you can do on a bus?

Tags: exercise, travel

I'm going to leave on a bus tour of Europe soon. I figure that all this time on a bus isn't going to be good for me, so I was wondering if there is any exercise I could do on the bus. For example, I've heard you can buy these things you can squeeze that will improve your grip strength (don't know what their proper name is). I'm curious if there is anything else that would work well in the confined space of a bus?

**Update**: I changed the title back to "What are exercises you can do on a bus?" as I think buses are a special case of space confinement and need to be treated separately.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do [15-20 minute workouts in the hotel?](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/2011/08/how-to-stay-fit-on-your-vacation/)

Comment: @IvoFlipse: Thanks, but I'll probably do both

Comment: Here is another [question/answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/how-do-i-exercise-on-the-plane/2932#2932) about exercises to do on a plane. You can do a lot with [resistance bands](http://youtu.be/kImPKVrIfKk?t=20s) when traveling. Bon Voyage!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's site with the focus of sitting exercises: http://www.sittingexercises.net/sitting-exercises-at-work.  I'm assuming that you won't have much room or usage of the isle...but if you did you may want to try FitDeck (http://fitdeck.com/fitness-bodyweight-only/bodyweight/), a set of bodyweight exercises for confined spaces (this product was developed by a navy seal for use in confined spaces like submarines).  I would recommend doing some exercising on the bus, but focusing on the trip and between bus ride workouts...and wait until you get back for the real exercising.

Answer (score 1):

Isometrics on neck, arms, legs, abs and lower back.  You can also go tense then release.  And the grips you suggested work too.

Answer (score 1):

Best is stand while traveling, you should be able to stand for an hour easily. While standing suck your tummy in so that it should feel like you are trying to touch your back with your navel internally. Protrude your outside and hold you breath while you chest is still out and breath slowly in and out as slow as possible. Place you hands in front of you chest in the 'namaste' position or praying position and flex you chest muscle as hard as you can. Once you can master all these moves without sacrificing the other try to lock it down in the possible with all the body parts in harmony, close your eyes and try to remain in the position for a 1 minute. Once you can handle it go for longer duration with higher intensity and more coordination on your breathing.